# "matListItemLine" property in Angular does not wrap text

Tags: html, css, angular, sass

As the title suggests, matListItemLine does not wrap text at all. Is this a bug?. I have been trying to use css to modify the wrap of text but it still does not work. Only had

or 
 seems to work except that will cause unintended wrapping of text where it is not needed.

```
<mat-list>
  <mat-list-item>
   <span matListItemTitle>Pepper</span>
    <span matListItemLine>Produced by a plant</span>
 </mat-list-item>
  <mat-list-item>
  <span matListItemTitle>Salt</span>
     <span matListItemLine>Extracted from sea water,Produced by dried and ground red 
      peppers</span>
   </mat-list-item>
 <mat-list-item>
     <span matListItemTitle>Paprika</span>
     <span matListItemLine>Produced by dried and ground red peppers,Extracted from sea 
     water</span>
     </mat-list-item>
</mat-list>
```

The snippet above does not wrap text in smaller screens and there would not be any need to wrap it in large screens. I was able to resolve my issue using regular ul and li tags. However, I would like to know why matListItemLine does not work. Can anyone share what they know please?

See link for angular docs https://material.angular.io/components/list/overview where it says "matListItemLine   Wraps a line of text within a list item." Maybe I misinterpreting this statement and it actually means something else?

Comment: In the doc you provided, it says: "To activate text wrapping, the lines input has to be set on the <mat-list-item> indicating the number of lines of text.", would this not help?

Comment: How would you go about doing that? something like this ? <mat-list-item input ="2">? @KaptainIglo

Comment: Yep. But the content to bre wrapped should not be in matListItemTitle/Line, it seems. It should be "unscoped". 
See example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jg3jkp?file=src/main.ts

Comment: that did not work. I will show you a screenshot . https://prnt.sc/Ko3fIKXIIxk-. Try to view that in Moto G4 ( 360 Width , 640 Height). 

Update I forgot to add mat-list-item {
  width: 200px;
}
it is working now

Comment: it does work. But not if there are more than 3 lines. As specified by the document: 
"A maximum of three lines is supported as per the Material Design specification." If your resolution is low and it goes on multiple lines, I guess it goes back to the initial behavior

Comment: It wraps when I add the mat-list-item { width: 200px; } but in desktop view it remains wrapped which would not be ideal since there is enough space to list it

Comment: For me it works... but if it doesn't for you, you can just wrap it manually with some xtra css. I've updated the stackblitz with an example.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Input `lines` of mat-list-item: https://material.angular.io/components/list/overview

Keep in mind though that `lines` can't go over 3, and that it only works on unscoped content (i.e. not under matListItemTitle/Line).

An alternative is to overwrite the behavior of mat-list-item with some extra css (see in the example).

Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jg3jkp?file=src/main.ts
Source:https://material.angular.io/components/list/overview

https://medium.com/ngconf/whats-new-in-angular-material-15-a196e606a33